# Escape quotes in Javascript/Chameleon template

Tags: javascript, python, chameleon

I am trying to pass a python dictionary from a chameleon template to a javascript function. But since the dictionary contains single quotes or ' which need to be escaped I get an error in firebug that says : `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. 
My code looks like this:

`<div id = "divsfp">
<input type="button" id="sfp" value="SFP"
onclick="get_sfp('${dict_value}')"></input></div>`

Where dict_value is a python dictionary. How can I escpae `'` in chameleon template before passing the data or in Javascript function itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *JSON encode* the dictionary. You don't then need to put quotes around the dictionary, and JavaScript will see it as a JavaScript object.

Comment: <code py> d = json.dumps(dict()) ; <code py> | -> <code JS> var myDict = d; <code js>

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes, encoded as `&quot`:

```
onclick="get_sfp(&quot;${dict_value}&quot;)"
```

Chameleon will escape any double-quotes in `dict_value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if this helps

"get_sfp('"+${dict_value}+"')"

Also from your implementation it seems that the dict_value is the variable you already know. So whats the problem accessing it from the get_sfp function.

Sorry couldn't comment as I still don't have that privilege.

Comment: This is not a python expression, the `"` quotes are delimiting an *XML attribute*.

Comment: @Pallab That doesn't work. It throws an error in template saying `ParseError: Unexpected end tag` (think because of the reason mentioned by Martijn).